# How to resolve the "Error occurred while loading translation library" Linux ODBC connection issue?

Tags: linux, odbc, netezza

After installing unixODBC and the Netezza drivers on a Linux client and configuring ~/.odbcinst.ini and ~/.odbc.ini data sources according to the documentation, attempting to connect to a Netezza PureData warehouse via some tools may yield an error similar to:

```
(Error) ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC]Error occurred while loading translation library (45) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

For example, this was output by the Python SQLAlchemy library via a DBAPI connection on a RHEL7 box (though has been reported from other distributions and other tools).

Does anyone know the detail of what is happening and how to properly resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extra info: I had a similar issue with the exact same error message.

Turns out I had `/etc/odbcinst.ini` set up with `UnicodeTranslationOption=utf8` for the `[NetezzaSQL]` driver.

Also a wrong (32-bit) driver was used.

Fixed with /etc/odbcinst.ini:

```
[NetezzaSQL]
Driver          = /opt/netezza/lib64/libnzodbc.so
DebugLogging    = true
LogPath         = /tmp
Trace           = 0
TraceAutoStop   = 0
TraceFile       = /tmp/trace.log
UsageCount      = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to work-around the issue, is to add the following lines to the specific data-source section of your ~/.odbc.ini file:

```
TranslationDLL=
TranslationName=
TranslationOption=
```

I don't know what other implications doing that may have (for example on non-English error messages or using unusual character encodings).

Answer (score 1):

Set the UnicodeTranslationOption to be UTF16 instead of UTF8 in your odbc.ini. Make sure that it has that setting in both the odbc.ini recognized by 'odbcinst -j' and also a spare copy in your home directory called just 'odbc.ini'. The latest netezza files seems to read the configuration without being a hidden file '.odbc.ini'

Answer (score 0):

You can also [enable Netezza ODBC debug log](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.datacon.doc/t_datacon_enabling_odbc_logging_unix_linux.html) to figure out detailed error. In odbcinst.ini , set
    DebugLogging = true